# In online machine learning algorithm linear regression stochastic gradient , when new training data comes do we have to mix it with prevoius data?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, linear-regression

Suppose I have 1 billion data set points, with which we already trained our machine learning model and obtained our parameters / weights . Now i receive another 100 data set points , how i train this new data set ? Deviating from linear regression , how do we train new examples of spam/not spam in spam filtering , if we had already trained let say 2 billion mails ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you should use a different algorithm (i.e. an [online algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm)).

I've never tried this in practice, but here's a paper from NIPS (a well-respected ML conference) that you may find useful: [Online Linear Regression and Its Application to Model-Based Reinforcement Learning](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3197-online-linear-regression-and-its-application-to-model-based-reinforcement-learning.pdf). (This same algorithm was suggested in an answer to [a similar question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23481/are-there-algorithms-for-computing-running-linear-or-logistic-regression-param).)